# Google Sheet Calculating if a value is with in a range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to populate a cell with "Yes"/"No", if stock price of a symbol falls between a range
of C2 and D2 .e.g.
`=IF(GOOGLEFINANCE(B2, "price") > C2 AND GOOGLEFINANCE(C2, "price") < D2, "Yes","No")`

Google sheet is not accepting this logic and giving error when I add 2nd part i.e. `AND GOOGLEFINANCE(C2, "price") < D2` to the logic.

What should be the correct logic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure google is the same as excel and you'd want to use the [AND](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093301?hl=en) function.

```
=IF(AND(GOOGLEFINANCE(B2, "price") > C2, GOOGLEFINANCE(B2,"price") < D2),"YES", "NO")
```